# How to uniquely assign color / line pattern to random users client side in an online drawing app?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, hash, websocket, client

I'm building a mobile online collaborative drawing app in ReactNative.  Users can join rooms of up to 4 total users where they can draw together and see each other's drawn shapes on a mutually-visible whiteboard.

I would like to assign each of the 4 users a unique style, e.g.

```
// Styles are a mix of color and lineStyle to accommodate color blindness
const style1 = { color: "#fff", lineStyle: "dashed" }
const style2 = { color: "#0f0", lineStyle: "solid" }
```

However, I would like to assign these styles client-side without needing to centrally manage and assign styles on a server.

The styles could be predefined from a set of 4 or more or could be generated dynamically.  The room has to handle users leaving and rejoining (e.g. manually or due to disconnects) as well as users leaving and other different users joining.  At any time t, no two users in a given room should be assigned the same style and a given user should retain the same style the entire time they are in the room and ideally reclaim the same style if they leave/rejoin in quick succession (e.g. due to a disconnect).

I'll be using something like Ably to push data between clients.

I could use Redis server-side to maintain unique maps of which user has which style but I'd rather do it client-side for ease of development.

Ideally the number of distinct styles will be low - I don't want a bunch of random colors that are small color distances apart.

***So given that I have a room R with 4 random users user1,...,user4 how can I assign styles to each user in a way that is highly likely to be unique and without collisions?***

Answer (score 1):

If a style is indeed the combination of both a `color` and a `lineStyle`, then you can evaluate the chance for a collision by using the formula of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), or birthday paradox.

Let's denote by `N` the number of differents possible styles (for instance, with 8 `colors` and 5 `lineStyle`, you will have `5*8=40` possible different styles).

Then, you can calculate the probability that, for `k` users, they all have a different style (note that you need `k<N`, or then trivially `P(X)=0`):

```
P(X) = (1 - 1/N) * (1 - 2/N) * ... * (1 - (k-1)/N) = product_{i from 1 to k-1} (1 - i/n)
```

You can understand the formula as follows:
If there are 2 users, the probability that they have a different style, is the probability that user2 has a differnt style than user1 (this probability is `1 - 1/N`)
With a 3rd user, you need the 1st and 2nd user to have a different style from each other, and the 3rd to have a different style than both the 1st and 2nd one.
And on, and on ....
Which gives the above formula.

Comment: Thanks.  This would lead to about an 85% chance of all 4 being unique, which is pretty good.  But 5 lineStyles is a lot.  Probably only about 3-4 would be distinguishable on a small mobile screen.  But the larger problem is how do I make the assignment of styles to userIds sticky client side?  It's easy to assign styles randomly, but I want a given user to consistently get the same style as much as possible.  That would require some kind of hash or something right?  I can't re-assign an existing style if a new user enters the room.

Comment: But you can use more than 8 colors .... or find a way for your client to check what style others are using, so it chooses another one. Or even simpler, a client sees itself as, say, blue, and sees the 3 others as pink, green and orange.

Comment: Agreed, but too many colors might be hard to visually distinguish and if clients are checking which colors the others are using then they need to reach some kind of quorum so that two clients don't simultaneously pick the same color.

Comment: Humm .... in this case you would have to go for a leader election, which is clearly overkill in your case .... maybe a coordination of it all on the server side ?